# Kotlin object. Which way of initialization is right?

Tags: kotlin

is there any difference between initialization of an object? 
Will the time field have different behavior or is it just the same as in Java (split declaration and initialization)? Thanks

```
object  DataHolder {
val time : MutableList<Long>

init {
    time = arrayListOf()
} ...
```

and this

```
object  DataHolder {
val time = arrayListOf<Long>() ....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally there's no difference at all between property initialization in the assignment or in the `init` block. You can inspect the generated bytecode with the `javap` tool to find out that it's exactly the same in both cases, modulo line numbers.

In your example however, there's a difference even from the source code perspective: in the first sample `time`'s type is declared to be `MutableList<Long>`, but in the second sample its type is not specified explicitly, so it has the type of the expression assigned to it. `arrayListOf<T>` returns `ArrayList<T>`, so `time`'s type in the second case is `ArrayList<Long>`. If you specify `MutableList<Long>` as `time`'s type in the second example, then indeed the produced outputs will be the same.